# Access controls of RteUploadDialog.aspx from Jquery - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I am inserting a picture from a richtextbox and it is popping up a dialog which is RteUploadDialog.aspx from _layouts folder i want to perform some validation on that popup .My question is where i need to add the J query to access the controls of it

I am having a custom master page but when i view the source of RteUploadDialog.aspx it is not including any of the HTML from my master page .

can some one please let me know where to add the jquery to access the elements of RteUploadDialog.aspx

I found this link but its saying undefined 
can soem one please let me know how can i access the HTML of RteUploadDialog.aspx

http://microscoff.com/2013/11/14/modify-upload-to-choices-for-discussions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify  \14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\RteDialog.master file to add reference to JQuery and Custom JavaScript file. But it is not recommended to modify Application Pages inside Layout folder so follow below best practices to modify application files.

[How to customize application pages in the Layouts folder in SharePoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944105)

Comment: Hi prasanjit Thanks for your reply but i dont want to modify layouts file .when i go to the library of the image the upload.aspx dialog also points from layouts folder it is having all jquery of my master page but this is not having .So is their a way to access it .

Comment: The Upload.aspx uses "DynamicMasterPageFile" attribute so it references the current Site Master page.But RteUploadDialog.aspx uses MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/RteDialog.master". So to add JS or JQuery you have to modify the file.